Using WebExecute to drop an image
I am new to this field, and sorry if the question is elementary.
I am trying to programmatically drop an image to the field at https://ocr.sanskritdictionary.com/ using WebExecute. Could someone help with how to do it? I could not find anything similar in the documentation or the workflows.
Thanks.
